# Search API Privileges in Coveo

Tags: json, api, postman, coveo

I am trying to use Coveo Search API in my project. I generated the Api key from the admin console page of Coveo. But when I send a query request  with the API key, I receive a response with status OK but the results attribute is always empty.

Access Privileges given  :

> Analytics > Analytics data > Push,
> Search > Execute Queries >  Allowed,
> Search > Impersonate >  Allowed.

My requirements:  Just a simple search API from Coveo that when sent a query through a request, send me all relevent answers with links of it in the response

Do i need  any more access privileges that a search Api should contain?

I tried it in POSTMAN :

Request : POST

URL :
`https://<ORG_ID>.org.coveo.com/rest/search/v2`

Body :

```
{
 "q" : "Example"
}
```

Response :

```
{
    "totalCount": 0,
    "totalCountFiltered": 0,
    "duration": 64,
    "indexDuration": 3,
    "requestDuration": 63,
    "searchUid": "5e7f7177-bbab-4b8b-99e4-06ac958dd052",
    "pipeline": "default",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "warnings": [
        "The searchHub in the query parameters was overridden by the searchHub in the token."
    ],
    "index": "pw6mqdaosk4qjucz3c5myx7kipu-10e67til-Indexer-1-x2cf3bwnmptiwgdqdiq6llslz4",
    "indexRegion": "us-east-1",
    "indexToken": "cHc2bXFkYW9zazRxanVjejNjNW15eDdraXB1LTEwZTY3dGlsLUluZGV4ZXItMS14MmNmM2J3bm1wdGl3Z2RxZGlxNmxsc2x6NA==",
    "refinedKeywords": [],
    "triggers": [],
    "termsToHighlight": {},
    "phrasesToHighlight": {},
    "queryCorrections": [],
    "groupByResults": [],
    "facets": [],
    "suggestedFacets": [],
    "categoryFacets": [],
    "results": []
}
```

What can be the possible reasons? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue with your query. Please try something generic, for example:

```
{
    "aq": "@sysrowid > 0"
}
```